# PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '211' for key 'id_album'

Tags: php, mysql

Excelente día. Espero que me puedan ayudar con un problema que lleva un par de días que no puedo solucionar.

El código es para una galería de imágenes, lo que hace es detectar si hay una carpeta nueva, si es el caso guarda el nombre de la carpeta en una tabla de base de datos y también el nombre de cada imagen. El problema es que solo guarda la primera imagen en la base de datos a pesar de que lee todas las imagens y me sale este error:

> PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '211' for key 'id_album'.

Esto lo hacia bien hasta que lo subí a un servidor. Espero que me puedan ayudar.

```
    <?php
    // La conexión se encuentra en otro archivo a la base de datos se encuentra en otro archivo

    $row = null;
    $dir_image= "imagenes/";
    $directorio = opendir("imagenes/");
    
    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT name_album FROM albums");
    $statement->execute();
    $name = $statement->fetchAll();
    
    while ($row = readdir($directorio)) {
    
        $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT name_album FROM albums WHERE name_album = '$row'");
        $statement->execute();
        $comparacion = $statement->fetch();
    
        if (($row != '.') && ($row != '..')) {
    
            if (!$comparacion) {
    
                $nfotos = count(glob("imagenes/$row/*", GLOB_BRACE));
                $fecha = date("d") . "/" . date("m") . "/" . date("Y");
                $statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO albums (id, name_album, upload_date, number_images) VALUES(null, :album, :upload, :nfotos)');
                $statement->execute(array(':album' => $row, ':upload' => $fecha, ':nfotos' => $nfotos));
    
                $nuevo_directorio = opendir($dir_image . $row);
    
                $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM albums WHERE name_album = '$row' ");
                $statement->execute();
                $var = $statement->fetch();
                $id = $var['id'];
    
                while ($imagen = readdir($nuevo_directorio)) {
                    if (($imagen != '.') && ($imagen != '..')) {
                        
                        $statementNameImage = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO name_images (id, name, id_album) VALUES(null, :image, :idalbum)");
                        $statementNameImage->execute(array(':image'=>$imagen, ':idalbum'=>$id)); // Aquí marca el error
    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    ?>
```

Comment: Cuál es el contenido de la tabla albums? Qué estás intentando insertar? El error dice que ya hay un registro con el mismo valor en la llave id_album sobre esa tabla.

Comment: La tabla albums tiene 5 columnas(id, name_album, description, upload_date y number_images), el id se pasa a otra tabla "name_images" donde se guardan los nombres de las imagenes (id, name y id_album), id_album es el id de la tabla albums

Comment: Es mucho más fácil si pones la definición de las tablas en la pregunta. Edítala y añades la información completa. Con eso intentamos ver sobre cuál campo está definida esa _key_. :)